# Getting the path of a file in C

Tags: c, file, environment-variables

I'm writing a C program that will process the content of a file. I know of one way to receive the file path, using the console input. But I need to use the other way, the "open file with" property.
On Windows, for example, one way of opening a file using a program is drag-dropping the file on the program executable.

Here's a photo of this:

[image]

I don't know how to get the file path in C, can you please tell me how to do this on Windows/MacOS/Linux?

Comment: This is operating system specific. Toolkits like [GTK](http://gtk.org/) could be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind guys! I found the answer to this question.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("%d\n", argc);
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; argv[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; envp[i] != NULL; i++)
        printf("%s\n", envp[i]);
    printf("---------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

If you copy the provided code and run the program using the drag-drop method, you'll notice that the path value is stored within the `argv array.

[image]

[image]

So, the answer would be this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
    if (argv[1] != NULL)
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    return 0;
}
```